# WPF Full Screen Issue with this.Width and this.Height

Tags: c#, wpf, window, size, fullscreen

I'm using WPF to write a program to use the entire screen. For the full screen effect, I wrote as

```
WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized"
```

Everything seems OK but when I use the *this.Width* and *this.Height* somewhere in the code, it's sometimes the value before the window is maximized. The code runs in some mouse event handlers, so the window should have already been maximized.

I said sometimes because it's about 20% likely that it would happen on .NET Framework 4.5. But when I change the project property to .NET Framework 3.0 or 3.5, it happens 100% of the times.

I think this should be a bug of .NET Framework but I need to get things better anyway. Is it happening because I didn't maximize the window properly? Or is there a better way to maximize a window to full screen?

PS. I've also tried this,

```
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;   
WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

but it's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties.